# How to UPDATE or INSERT based on multiple columns returning the same data, without having access to the unique ID

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, replace, insert

I have a table of data for Holiday Park availability
an example of which being:

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>api_key</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>category_id</th>
<th>sites_available</th>
<th>price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>asfe4t4gs</td>
<td>2019-11-08</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>ydfhswre3354</td>
<td>2019-12-08</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>150</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

The problem I am having is, we send a JSON result of data to update or insert into this table. It needs to check if the api_key, date and category_id are already in the table and update them with the other fields (price and sites_available), otherwise it needs to insert them as new entries.

This is a Wordpress plugin.

We have tried looping over it all and determining if it exists or not but due to the amount of data being passed in, it was far too slow and timing out (thousands of entries). We have also tried to use the $wpdb->replace method however it doesn't seem to work as it is adding new entries everytime.

```php
   foreach ($result['categories'] as $category) {
    if (empty($category['category_id']))
        throw new Exception('category_id is empty');
            if (empty($category['dates']))
            throw new Exception('dates is empty');
            foreach ($category['dates'] as $date) {
                if(empty($date['date']))
                throw new Exception('date is empty');
                $wpdb->replace(
                    $availability_table_name,
                                        array(
                        "sites_available" => $date['sites_available'],
                        "price" => $date['price'],
                            'api_key' => $result['api_key'],
                        'instance_id' => $result['instance_id'],
                        'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                        "date_availability" => $date['date'],
                    )
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the SQL table? Then you can do this with a SQL statement, like:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, sites_available, price) VALUES(1, "2", 3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sites_available="2", price=3;
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

If you want to check if the entry in the html table already exist: best would be if you write all the data into an array once and check if the array key exists.

Regards Tom